# Is there a way to backtrack / figure out what e-mails have been sent with mail() in php?

Tags: php, email, history

I was fixing a website that was under attack.

I saw that some hacker put his e-mail address into the code to send credit card information to himself.

I obviously removed that e-mail address.

But, just to be sure, is there a way I can check what e-mails actually are getting sent from the server / the application?

e.g. is there an outbox folder or some history log of what e-mails are getting sent?

the code base is huge and it would take a long time to figure out all places where e-mails are getting sent are not infected.

Comment: you should look at the maillog on the server that runs the site.

Answer (score 1):

`sendmail` (or similar MTAs) will, by default, log transactions so you can see *who* was emailed *when*. But it's highly unlikely actually copies of email content will ever be logged any where in a web server environment.

On Centos/RHEL, sendmail logs will be in `/var/log/maillog`.

I would at least find all instances of `mail(` in your code project through something as simple as [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) to ensure you check everything ... although I find it unlikely that this is a single injection vulnerability in a mail form or similar.